# Queried two MySQL tables; cannot display some results?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a query that works perfectly:

```
$query = "Select * FROM prefix_posts 
 WHERE post_type='custompost1' 
       OR post_type='custompost2' 
 AND post_status='publish' 
 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

But it only shows two fields in a table: POST TITLE, DATE

(Note: This displays WordPress posts on a non-WordPress site. So the WP loop does not work here. I need a query.)

I need to add a third entry -- POST TITLE, DATE, CUSTOM FIELD

So I need to obviously alter the query.

This was my best attempt so far:

```
$query = "SELECT prefix_posts.* 
 FROM prefix_posts, prefix_postmeta
 WHERE prefix_posts.ID = prefix_postmeta.post_id 
    AND prefix_postmeta.meta_key = 'mymeta' 
    AND prefix_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND ( prefix_posts.post_type = 'custompost1'
       OR prefix_posts.post_type = 'custompost2' )
 ORDER BY prefix_posts.id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Problem is, it does not show any of the results for "custompost2".

Ideas?

Comment: 1) if selecting all columns (from the "select *" syntax) from the table returns only 2 fields -post title and date - seems that you should first add a column to the table (Custom Field). 2) Regarding a query that shows no result - one of the where conditions must be failing. Try commenting out one by one to see which one is the problematic one.

Comment: post_type is the column. And from that column, I only want 'custompost1' and custompost2' post types. (There are other post types. And the query returns custompost1, just not the second. It was fine in the first query that worked.)

Comment: This was it. There was indeed an issue within the database that I'd not noticed. Thanks! (Now the issue is displaying the new 3rd field data. And for now, I just have to assume the query is correct.)

Comment: I think so, because "select * from ..." retrieves all fields from the table you specify.

Comment: I actually had to add prefix_postmeta.* to the select, as it was not actually pulling the meta_value column. Once that was done, the php fell into place as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts
WHERE (
post_type =  'post_type_1'
OR post_type =  'post_type_2'
)
AND post_status =  'publish'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: That's what I started with.

Comment: it's working for me..here is difference `WHERE (post_type OR post_type)`